# Render _.template using object w/ numeric keys

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Ran into some weird behavior using underscore.js's `template` method:

```
var test = ['first', 'test'];
console.log(_.template('this is a <%= 1 %> ', test));
```

(Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adamb/mbD6E/)

This snippets outputs: **"this is a 1"**, while the expected result is **"this is a test"**.

No errors are thrown. I've studied the [source-code](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L=1176-1177) and there's no obvious explanation for this result. It's required that I use interpolation only in my template. I've tried converting the array explicitly to a collection using `_.extend({}, test)`, but no dice.

How can I get this working?

Comment: The [template](http://underscorejs.org/#template) function expects a object, not an array.

Comment: @Jack When I explicitly convert it to an object I get the same result (as noted in the question.) Please see fiddle for that specific example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the compiled template code with:

```
_.template('this is a <%= 1 %> ').source
```

which gives this function:

```
function(obj){
var __p='';var print=function(){__p+=Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, '')};
with(obj||{}){
__p+='this is a '+
( 1 )+
' ';
}
return __p;
}
```

the key part is:

```
with(obj){
  (1)
}
```

because 1 isn't a valid property/variable name,  it doesn't try to match the properties of the object you are templating, so just prints out '1'.

if you were to use an object like `{zero: 'first', one: 'test'}` and a template of `'this is a <%= one %> '`, then this would look like:

```
with(obj){
  (one)
}
```

which is kind of equivelant of `obj.one`

Answer (score 1):

A number is not a valid javascript reference.

Here you probably want to write it this way: `<%= this[1] %>`.

If that's not working, then pass your array to an object key:

```
_.template('this is a <%= list[1] %> ', { list: test })
```

Comment: `<%= this[1] %>` doesn't work, while the second snippet works.

Comment: Although it's not a valid reference, I thought (perhaps _hoped_) that it would attempt to retrieve the value from the collection via bracket notation, in which case `test[1]` _is_ valid.

Comment: `1` is a valid expression and `<%= ... %>` wraps expressions.